# Auto resize only works on first selected textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Heey everyone i am working on a notes website. But now i wanna be able to resize multiple textareas but my code only works on the first selected textarea.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1or08jkm/

```
var content = $("#banner-message");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        content.append(` <textarea id="note" class="autoExpand" type="text" 
name="id">Text</textarea>
     `)
        }
$(document)
    .one('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function () {
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function () {
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0, rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you change .one to .on, is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Actually yes that is what i was looking for such a stupid mistake.

Comment: I'll post as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our comments, the solution was simply changing .one to .on:

```
var content = $("#banner-message");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    content.append(` <textarea id="note" class="autoExpand" type="text" name="id">Text</textarea>
 `)
    }
$(document)
.on('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function () {
    var savedValue = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    this.value = savedValue;
})
.on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function () {
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows') | 0, rows;
    this.rows = minRows;
    rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
    this.rows = minRows + rows;
});
```

By way of explanation, the use of .one will only fire a maximum of once per element/event type. In your instance, this means your code was only executed on the first textarea. Using .on instead lets your code run for each textarea.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `.one(…)` is binding to `document`, and not to each `textarea`, and will therefore trigger at most once per event it's listening to. (The event listener is registered on `document`, and it filters all events bubbled up to `document` by the selector argument.)

In order to get `.one(…)` to trigger once per each text area, you probably want to bind the listener to the textarea:

```
$('textarea.autoExpand')
  .one('focus.autoExpand', function () {
    …
})
```

If you need the listener to be on the document but only trigger once per element, you may need to instead use `.on(…)` and do something like:

```
$(document)
  .on('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function () {
    if(this.isSetupForAutoExpand) return;
    … (your setup code here)
    this.isSetupForAutoExpand = true;
})
```